# How to group elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a python list:

```
['AM43',
 'AM22',
 'AM51',
 'AM43',
 'AM22',
 'AM51',
 'AM43',
 'AM22',
 'AM51']
```

I want the output to be a list:

```
['AM43',
 'AM43',
 'AM43',
 'AM22',
 'AM22',
 'AM22',
 'AM51',
 'AM51',
 'AM51']
```

I tried `sort()` but that also rearranges the order. I don't want that. I want the output to be in the same order as the input list.

Comment: for small lists `sorted(lst, key=lst.index)`

Comment: There is no inbuilt function that will do what you are after. This seems like a really interesting problem, and something that might even be a good interview question. Use the opportunity to improve your problem solving skills. If you absolutely need a hint, a data structure that will help is a list of lists. Appending to that will allow you to maintain the order you want.

Comment: How can you group values without changing their order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a dict that stores the index of the first occurrence of each value, and use the dict to perform the sort:

```
lst = ["AM43", "AM22", "AM51", "AM43", "AM22", "AM51", "AM43", "AM22", "AM51"]

ix = {k: i for i, k in reversed(list(enumerate(lst)))}
res = sorted(lst, key=ix.get)
# ['AM51', 'AM51', 'AM51', 'AM22', 'AM22', 'AM22', 'AM43', 'AM43', 'AM43']
```

Edit: @emsimposon92 provides a 2-pass linear-time solution implementable as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

ctr = Counter(lst)
visited = set()
res2 = list()
for x in lst:
    if x in visited:
        continue
    res2.extend([x] * ctr[x])
    visited.add(x)
```

Comment: For the order they want remove`reversed()`

Comment: I was composing a similar solution, `seq = sorted(seq, key=seq.index)`, which works along the same lines. But this is more efficient since `dict.get` is O(1) and `list.index` is O(N).

Comment: Does this store the *last index*?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon yep, it does. The example data makes it unclear.

Comment: If you change the last item of the data to "AM43", the order is wrong! The dict does not hold the right indices.

Comment: Note this common algorithm with `visited` replicates `toolz.unique` or the [itertools unique_everseen recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: Hmm, maybe you _did_ need the `reversed` after all. But it needed to be outside the enumerate, rather than inside. But you can't natively reverse an enumerate object, so you'd need `{k: i for i, k in reversed(list(enumerate(lst)))}`

Comment: Yep, shame that there is no easy option to enumerate in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a list for each unique number and then just concatenate them based on the original input order.

Answer (score 1):

Following Yakym Pirozhenko's answer, to get the appropriate order you need to reverse-enumerate `lst` when building the index dict:

```
lst = ["AM43", "AM22", "AM51", "AM43", "AM22", "AM51", "AM43", "AM22", "AM43"]

ix = {k: i for i, k in zip(range(len(lst), -1, -1), reversed(lst))}

res = sorted(lst, key=ix.get)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `collections.Counter`, `itertools` and `toolz.unique`. Note the last uses a 3rd party library, but the source code is just an `itertools` [unique_everseen recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import repeat, chain
from toolz import unique

lst = ['AM43', 'AM22', 'AM51', 'AM43', 'AM22',
       'AM51', 'AM43', 'AM22', 'AM51']

c = Counter(lst)
uniques = unique(lst)

res = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(u, c[u]) for u in uniques))

res

['AM43', 'AM43', 'AM43',
 'AM22', 'AM22', 'AM22',
 'AM51', 'AM51', 'AM51']
```